# Webpack 4 fileloader not moving images

Tags: webpack

As a webpack beginner i am using this https://github.com/vadimmarkov/webpack-es6-sass-boilerplate to learn to use webpack 4 but i haven't managed to get the fileloader working. My /images folder is simply not moved to the /build folder. Would anyone kindly help me fix this issue?

[image: Webpack config]

[image: My filestructure]

Comment: What happens if you remove `publicPath` property from both fonts and images? Could you please post `output` from webpack configuration too?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using require/import for the the images in your Javascript? It will only include those.

Comment: I added "import headerLarge from '../images/header-large.jpg';" to my index.js and the image is moved to the build folder and is renamed "header-large.f03260f1.jpg".

Sadly it still doesn't appear in the browser. 

Do i still reference this image with <img src="images/header-large.jpg" alt="Main header" /> in my html file or do i need to do something else?

Comment: You can use ```name: '[name].[ext]'``` instead and you can reference the image in your HTML as usual.